# Xamarin app crashes when discovering BLE peripherals

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, core-bluetooth

I'm making a cross-platform app in Xamarin and currently I'm stuck in trying to get a simple BLE scan up and running. The app crashes ugly, and I've symbolized and hunted the issue down to the file "mini-exceptions.c", line 2360.

Basically, it says;

```
find_last_handler_block (StackFrameInfo *frame, MonoContext *ctx, gpointer data)
{  
    int i;
    gpointer ip;
    FindHandlerBlockData *pdata = data;
    MonoJitInfo *ji = frame->ji;

    if (!ji)
        return FALSE;
```

So, in short; I'm missing the "MonoJitInfo", returning false which in turn throws an exception and I'm done.

But -- I don't get it. Why this "mono"-stuff? I'm developing for the new Xamarin Unified, and AFAIK there's not a single reference in the project to any classic MonoTouch-stuff?

I'm a Xamarin newbie so I'm trying me best to put the puzzle together here...

As for my application, and crash occurs when I create my CBCentralManager to use the "DefaultGlobalQueue", but I'm not getting any crash when I use the MainQueue as DispatchQueue -- but I'm not getting any discovered peripherals either so I'm guessing that it's something related to my DispatchQueue...?

I'm lost, I guess... Any hints are highly valued. Does CoreBluetooth in Xamarin.iOS require Mono?

## EDIT;

I'm actually getting a critical error before my native crash, and I see some strange mono-touch references in there too...;

```
critical: Stacktrace:
critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:62
critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0001c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:45
critical:   at iOSMyApp.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00008] in /Users/markus/Xamarin/MyApp/iOS/iOSMyApp/Main.cs:17
critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
```

## Edit -- with code snippets

My BLE implementation is the iOS-native class implementing an interface in a shared-project setup where all the business-logic is managed.

I've tried both a lambda-variant;

```cs
private CBCentralManager Central;

readonly AutoResetEvent stateChanged = new AutoResetEvent (false);
async Task WaitForState (CBCentralManagerState state)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Waiting for state: " + state);

    while (Central.State != state) {
        await Task.Run (() => stateChanged.WaitOne ());
    }
}

internal NativeBleCentralTransport ()
{
    Central = new CBCentralManager (DispatchQueue.MainQueue);

    Central.DiscoveredPeripheral += (object sender, CBDiscoveredPeripheralEventArgs e) => {
        Console.WriteLine ("DiscoveredPeripheral: " + e.Peripheral.Name);
    };

    Central.UpdatedState += (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
        Console.WriteLine ("UpdatedState: " + Central.State);
        stateChanged.Set();
    };

    Central.ConnectedPeripheral += (object sender, CBPeripheralEventArgs e) => {
        Console.WriteLine ("ConnectedPeripheral: " + e.Peripheral.Name);
    };

    Central.DisconnectedPeripheral += (object sender, CBPeripheralErrorEventArgs e) => {
        Console.WriteLine ("DisconnectedPeripheral: " + e.Peripheral.Name);
    };

    Central.FailedToConnectPeripheral += (object sender, CBPeripheralErrorEventArgs e) => {
    };
}

public async Task<bool> SetupTransport ()
{
    //Wait for state...
    WaitForState(CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn);

    //Scan for *any* peripheral at the moment...
    CBUUID[] uuids = null;
    Central.ScanForPeripherals (uuids);

    //Wait for things to happen...
    await Task.Delay (10000);

    return true;
}
```

... and the other "extend CBCentralManagerDelegate class"-approach;

```cs
internal class NativeBleCentralTransport : CBCentralManagerDelegate, ISessionTransport
{
    private CBCentralManager BleManager;

    internal NativeBleCentralTransport ()
    {
        //Create BLE manager and hook-up ourselves as delegate
        BleManager = new CBCentralManager(this, DispatchQueue.MainQueue);
    }

    public async Task<bool> SetupTransport ()
    {
        //The manager will automatically kick "UpdateState" for us to indicate the status of the native BLE-interface (e.g., enabled or disabled?),
        //so let's just sit back and await completion of discovery

        Task.Delay (10000);

        return true;
    }

    #region BLE delegate overrides

    override public void UpdatedState (CBCentralManager mgr)
    {
        //State change occured! Let's see if we should start 
        if (BleManager.State == CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn) 
        {
            CBUUID[] uuids = null;
            BleManager.ScanForPeripherals (uuids);
        } 
    }

    public override void DiscoveredPeripheral (CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSDictionary advertisementData, NSNumber RSSI)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Discovered: " + peripheral.Name);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

## Problem summary

The idea is essentially that when a *transport* is setup (**SetupTransport**), the BLE interface should kick-in and discover/connect to a peripheral by blocking the invoking thread until it's done and ready for action.

But -- my app crashes when it discovers a peripheral on the iOS-native side. Not in my code -- I never see my debug-messages on the Console, but I've found it when symbolizing the native crash logs...

So, essentially; I'm not doing anything strange, it very straight-forward I'd say, BUT it is a shared-project setup and it's my first Xamarin-project, which makes me less comfortable with the terminology.. I'm using the Unity API. I'm currently suspecting that this is actually a project-setup/constraint/reference-thing and I'm therefore rebuilding a new test-project which is NOT a shared project but a native iOS-thing just to see that I can make a simple BLE discovery without crashing and then I'll take it from there I guess.

Any insights and suggestions are appreciated!
/Markus

## Results

I did a test-solution in Xamarin, with only one project; a single-page iOS-template thing and just added my class in the "DidAppear" method in the View-controller, and everything works...

Hence, this is **NOT** a code/syntax-issue (unless there are rules that I'm not aware of for shared-project setups?), but a shared-project issue/Xamarin-setup issue. Any recommendations out there on how to setup a shared-project. Any missing references that an experienced pair of eyes can find by looking at the crash-traces?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Yes, it was related to shared-project setup and more specifically *where* my BLE native transport class was created.

Turns out, the *CBCentralManager* **must be created by the main-thread**, and I created an instance from a function with *async* attribute.

So by simply putting my *NativeBleCentralTransport* instance as a private variable created when the app boot-up, and use that object reference in my *async* function, everything works (which is also why everything worked nicely when I created a native iOS-project since I just brute-force played with an instance of  *NativeBleCentralTransport* directly from the *ViewDidAppear* function.